# How to use createDisposition with BigQuery insertAll

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

insertAll will fail if no table with that name exists. So currently we run a process to create the table, then re-runs insertAll once the table exists.

With every other BigQuery API call you can use a createDisposition to create the table if it doesn't exist.

My question, is there something like this for insertAll? If not, why not! Haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [templateSuffix](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/insertAll#templateSuffix) property for insertAll
It does what you expect

From documentation

> [Experimental] If specified, treats the destination table as a base
>   template, and inserts the rows into an instance table named
>   "{destination}{templateSuffix}". BigQuery will manage creation of the
>   instance table, using the schema of the base template table. See
>   https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#template-tables
>   for considerations when working with templates tables.

So, request should look something like below

```
var request = {
  projectId: "yourProject",
  datasetId: "yourDataset",
  tableId: "yourTable",
  resource: {
    "kind": "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest",
    "skipInvalidRows": true,
    "ignoreUnknownValues": true,
    "templateSuffix": "YourTableSuffix",
    "rows": ...
  },
```

with resulting destination table - `yourTableYourTableSuffix`

Comment: Care to provide a sample payload?